# Using liquid want to iterate through list of JSON objects and append code to all except second to last object

Tags: loops, html-email, liquid

I am creating a transactional email and reading a JSON object that contains product information (product image and description) and displaying those contents in the email. For each element, that I am displaying, I append HTML code (padding) as it loops through the object. I want to iterate through JSON object, but for the last element, DO not append additional HTML code.

I have currently set up a for loop that reads the products and appends a table row that displays a line at the end of each product that is called from the JSON object. I am unable to find a way to have this line not appear on the final object.

```
{% for products in merge_vars.order.products %}
{% for products in merge_vars.order.products %}
<!-- TOP CARD -->
<table>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" height="20"
            style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <!-- IMAGE -->
        <td class="img-small" align="left" width="80" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0 20px;">
            <img alt="{{ products.name }}" src="{{ products.image }}" width="80" height="80" border="0"
                 style="width:80px; height:80px;">
        </td>
        <!-- IMAGE END -->

        <!-- PRODUCT DESCRIPTION -->
        <td align="left" width="210" style="padding: 0 20px 0 0;">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left">

                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: 0.4px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-weight:normal;">
                        <span style="color: #868686;">
                        {{ products.description }}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <!-- LINE and Bottom Padding -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" height="20"
            style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" width="100%" height="2"
            style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- LINE END -->

</table>
<!-- TOP CARD END -->
<!-- ADDITIONAL PRODUCTS END -->
{% endfor %}
```

So when I go through each object I get the expected bottom padding and line, but I cannot get this padding and line to NOT appear on the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this like that:

```
{% unless forloop.last %}
    HTML Code you do not want to iterate for the last item in the loop.
{% endunless %}
```